# После нажатия кнопки submit страница прыгает вверх

Tags: html

onclick='return false' не даёт отправить данные на сервер. Какие ещё варианты

Comment: Бить не будем, код покажите.

Comment: покажите какой у вас код. форма отправляется js или сама по себе ? кнопка submit у вас `<input type="submit">` или что-то другое ?

Comment: вот
<input id="commentSend" type="submit" value="Высказаться" onclick="return false">

Answer (score 1):

если я правильно понял вопрос, через имя подгружать в хэш #имя - то что нужно

Answer (score 0):

ajaxSubmit jquery поищите. Он будет отправлять форму без перезагрузки, если возможно.